# I get stuck almost every time in printing pdf files on Kyocera FS1020MFP and Brother DCP-L2520D printers with ubuntu 20

Tags: drivers, printing, pdf

I tried several times installing and uninstalling the printer drivers for both the printers but not able to get print. Although, Brother DCP-T220 is working fine at the same time.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  So you're asking about a Ubuntu Core 20 installation?  (*note: the year formatted products eg. 20 are different to the more commonly used year.month products they are based on; 20 is intended for headless server operation only being a flavor of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server*)

Comment: Some more details are needed. What is the Ubuntu version? What drivers did you install?

Comment: And is it only with PDF files? Please avoid posting red herrings...